How to use npm link dependency with Next.js Turbopack?
I'm developing a package, which I also need to test with local next.js project.
The structure is:
my-package@1.2.3 C:\Users\mist\code\my-package
├── package.json
├── src
├── example/
    ├── package.json
    ├── app/
    ├── next.config.ts

I did run npm link ../ --save in the /example directory.
The /example/package.json now contains:
  "dependencies": {
    "my-package": "file:..",
  }

When I run the example app with next dev --turbo I get the error:
./app/test/action.ts:3:1

Module not found: Can't resolve 'my-package'
  1 | "use server";
  2 |
> 3 | import { test } from "my-package";
    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  4 | import { z } from "zod";
  5 |
 

How can I use a local package with the Next.js Turbopack?
The non-turbo mode works for me though, so the link setup is correct.
